# How do I store several .jpg and .png files in an array? Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, jpeg, store

So here is a full explanation. 
Currently, I'm building an Android app wherein there will be 3 to 5 images at a time. Then, after pressing an imagebutton (like ¨Forward¨ or ¨Next¨), another set of 3 to 5 images will appear. 
The set of images will be as follows: first, a .jpg image at the background; second, an smaller .png image in the middle; third, an even smaller .png image up front; along with an imagebutton. And so on.

I'm using Android Studio. I know that I should connect an array in the .java file with ImageView in the .xml file using an object. But, I still can't picture the code in my head.

I thought of using an array, otherwise my .xml file will be massive. I assume. I will do some trial-and-error and post my results, but any help is welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the images inside `res/drawable` folder. Suppose the name of the images will be , `a.jpg a1.png a2.png`. Now in your java code you can create an integer array like

```
 int icons[] = {R.drawable.a, R.drawable.a1, R.drawable.a2};
```

Now you can use these values according to your requirements.

Comment: Thanks thanks. Your answer is incredibly helpful. ^-^ I still have a doubt though, In the .xml file, how do I set up ImageView (or is there another way that I may display the image). My guess is that I have to make an object where by I can set and, then clean in order to, set  images again, right?

Comment: In xml inside `<ImageView/>` tag , use `android:src="@drawable/a"`. To change the source of imageview programmatically , `imgview.setImageResouce(R.drawable.a)`. Please upvote and accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Thanks! It did help me. I still can't upvote now (I'm still at 8 reputation points) but I will when I can. Thanks. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

save the image names which are there in res/drawable folder to an array of strings, and set the ImageView src by the names present in that array.

Answer (score 0):

At first, create a list of all image resources:

```
List<Integer> myImages = Arrays.asList(R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3);
```

Wherever in your code, just access a random or a specific image as follows:

```
int currentIndex = 0; // your index
myImageView.setImageResource(bgImageList.get(currentIndex));
```